# What is the preferred way to serve web applications written in Lisp?

Tags: web-applications, lisp, nginx, httpserver

I've been researching modules for Nginx (my preferred webserver) to serve a Lisp webapp, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Is there modules for Nginx, or is there better ways to serve Lisp webapps? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Nginx support proxying, you could always proxy to a Hunchentoot server running on localhost.

Comment: nginx is first a proxy, and only incidentally a server

Answer (score 0):

There's always [mod_lisp](http://www.cliki.net/mod_lisp) if you're interested in using Apache. (It's like Phusion Passenger for ruby webapps.) Nginx is nice but you have to compile it every time you want to extend it, which isn't too intuitive. Keeps it fast though. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use hunchentoot behind nginx. without any module installation separately you can direct requests over nginx to hunchentoot.

```
upstream hunchentoot { server 127.0.0.1:5050; }
```

and somewhere in `location {}` directive;

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {

proxy_pass http://hunchentoot;
}
```

this works for me. nginx/1.4.2.